# JAXB XML Constraints, using annotations

Tags: java, jaxb, constraints

I have next code

```
   @XmlAttribute
   private String workstation;
```

Can I make constraints for this field, for example 'max length'? (using annotations)

Comment: Try OvalValidator. It has a pre-defined set of validations (annotation-based) that should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out implementations of [JSR 303 - Bean Validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303).  It is a standard for specifying constraints on a POJO via annotations.

- http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303